# rxjs access to object value by key

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an observable which is an Array of objects with key-value-pairs.

I can get access to the first element of this array by:

```
const source = this.store.select('news').pipe();
    const element = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val.news[0]));
```

It logs me the object properly in the console.

If I try to log just the newsId by

const source = this.store.select('news').pipe();
    const element = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val.news[0].newsId));

I get an error "Cannot read property 'newsId' of undefined".

How could the object be defined as a whole but if I try to access the object it tells me that it's undefined?

Comment: Can you show us the code of `store.select` and the array containing the data ?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "code of store.select"? I just go for the "news"-state. How could I show you the array? There is no opportunity to load up screenshots...

Comment: The observable delivers an object "news". This object contains an array of "News" and each element of the array contains some key-value-pairs. Amongst these key-value-pairs there is a newsID which contains a number. I would like to get the value of the newsId of the element 0 of the array.

Comment: @JJJanezic I agree, this sounds very strange. You are sure you are doing both the 'console.log(val.news[0])' and the 'console.log(val.news[0].newsId)' at the exact same place in the code, nothing else is changed?

Comment: Yes, I do w/o newsId -> it works; I change the code -> it does not.

Comment: @JJJanezic the code inside the select method

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple reasons.

- Maybe the news array's first element doesn not initially contain a `newsId` field and then news[0] printed in the console is later updated by reference
- Maybe the news array contains some `undefined` values along with valid news.

So, first try to log the whole array `val.news` and make sure all the elements in that array are defined. Also make sure all the events coming from that Observable are what you expect them to be.

Anyway, the `pipe()` is needed only if you plan to use some rxjs operators, otherwise it doesn't make any sense there (actually it can confuse newbies).

Comment: This sounds to be the right approach. There are 2 components on this site. The first one contains the respective code whereas the second fetches the data from the server and puts it in the store. Therefore, when the first component gets initialised the data is not in the store yet and the observable is undefined. After a second the data gets loaded into the store and the observable (containing the array) delivers the array. How could I avoid this effect?

Comment: You can filter undefined values like this `this.store.select('news').pipe(filter(v => !!v));`. There are multiple ways to do this, might also be a good idea to check that v is an array and that it has elements. Alternatively you could initialise the store state as an empty array instead of undefined, but that depends on your implementation..

Comment: Thank you, currently I have implemented a try / catch. This works good, but is this a good practice?

Comment: It is not. You should either handle the case inside your callback or filter events which you are not interested in using the `filter` operator. The try-catch is a synchronous construct and doesn't really fit (as it is) into the observable world

Comment: I've tried to do it in the callback, but was not successfull. What's wrong with this code? THX!!! `this.latestNewsIdSub = this.store.select('news').subscribe(
      appState => this.latestNewsId = appState.news[0].newsId,
      () => this.latestNewsId = 0);`

Comment: Try with `this.latestNewsId = appState && appState.news && appState.news[0].newsId`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. Interesting enough that I get a second error (besides the original one): `Cannot read property 'outlet' of null

Comment: A check of the length of the array is not possible, because the array is not defined at this point of time and the property length is not avail. Instead of a try catch I have now implemented an if condition. Is this considered to be a good practice? `this.latestNewsIdSub = this.store.select('news').subscribe(
      appState => {
        if (appState.news[0]) {
          this.latestNewsId = appState.news[0].newsId;
        } else {
          this.latestNewsId = 0;
        }
      }
    );`

Comment: This last one is the same as `this.latestNewsId = (appState && appState.news && appState.news[0].newsId) || 0`. Anyway you should implement filtering on a higher level as stated before to reduce this code complexity